# Are there eclipse settings that can dramatically improve JavaScript editor performance on large files?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, performance

Sometimes I have to work on a project with very large javascript files (> 30k lines). I have no control over the decision to split them into several files.

Under these conditions, the javascript editor becomes very slow. Event typing a character can take up to 2 seconds. Is there a hidden setting that would disable the right things to have just syntax highlighting and basic text editiong features ? So I wouldn't have to switch to a text editor in which I don't have all convenient eclipse shortcuts...

Comment: Maybe you should switch to using a good editor?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine You mean instead of using eclipse or you know a good plugin for my need ? I wont participate into a "IDE vs Text editor + commandline build" troll ;=) If my issue are no solution, I'll draw the conclusions myself...

Comment: Instead of using eclipse, of course. I was just trolling :)

Comment: Well be happy that's what I currently do ;=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer after all this time, looks like the answer is no...

Answer (score 0):

Right now I don't have this problem, but if I did I'd raise a bug against JSDT in the [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) and see where that takes me.

Your use case is pretty unusual and it's possible that the developers and most users never encountered it. It's not guarantee to deliver a performance optimisation in a timely manner but it's the next best thing to rolling up your sleeves and submitting a patch.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to your problem: right click tour Projets -> Settings -> Javascript -> Include Path

Open the Source tab and remove all the folders. Click OK.

Enjoy your javascript!